# Scaling the spacing between StackPanels

Tags: wpf

I am having problems scaling the whitespace between three horizontally aligned StackPanels. There is one overarching StackPanel under which is a WrapPanel to arrange three  more StackPanels (and the labels above them). Underneath them is a StackPanel which expands to fill the whole window:

[image: WPF code]

It looks fine at the smaller sizes, but when I expand the window, the panels are still crowded to the left. I would like the StackPanels to move apart, using more of the window.

I am not wedded to to any particular architecture - if the WrapPanel or another control is an issue, I have no problem using another control / design, as long as the three StackPanels remain side-by-side.

Here is the WPF code I have:

```
<WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="One" />
        <ContentControl>
            <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Export" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="180" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />                            
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </ContentControl>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox></TextBox>
            <Button Name="NewSitePlan"</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel MaxWidth="320" Width="300">
        <TextBlock Text="Two" />
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <DataGrid>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" MinWidth="220" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox></TextBox>
            <Button></Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Width="300">
        <TextBlock Text="Three" />
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="250">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" MinWidth="150" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="RFID" Binding="{Binding Path=Data.RFID}" MinWidth="50" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox></TextBox>
            <Button></Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</WrapPanel>

<StackPanelVerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <TextBlock Text="Sites" />
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <DataGrid>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Export" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" MinWidth="120" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Path=Data.Description}" MinWidth="200" />
                ...
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox></TextBox>
        <Button></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go about laying this out using a grid if I know beforehand how many items are going to exist. You could probably get the `WrapPanel` to work, but this is what I would do:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions >
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Background="LightCyan">
        <TextBlock Text="One" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Background="LightCoral">
        <TextBlock Text="Two" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Background="LightBlue">
        <TextBlock Text="Three" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Background="LightGreen">
        <TextBlock Text="Low" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Looks like this: [image]

I like to use background colors so I can see the layout.